# Datasheet view query in sub form determining controls' status on parent form

Tags: ms-access

I have a search query that is displayed in a sub form that is in datasheet view.

When selecting a record from this subform, I need to have users click a button (for tracking purposes) to access the record's data on other parts of the form. Currently, the Access Record Button is set to enabled = true when the query runs (via a submit button).

The problem with this is that if a search yields no results, the access record button is still click-able and tries to access a record that doesn't exist; giving me: "Run-time error 2427: You entered an expression that has no value"

Is there a way to disable that button if the query returns no results or if no record is selected?

EDIT: Code for the button at this point.

```
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
Me!SearchResults.Form.RecordSource = "qryPendingCriteriaCIP"
Me!SearchResults.Form.Requery
Me!SearchResults.Form.Visible = True


If Forms!frm_SearchMulti!SearchResults.Form.RecordCount > 0 Then

Me.cmdExport.Enabled = True
Me.SearchResults.Enabled = True


Me.cmdPass.Enabled = True
Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the button on the main form and do you mean you wish to check that there are records in the subform?

```
If Me.MySubformControlName.Form.Recordset.RecordCount>0 Then
```

Or to check a row:

```
If Me.MySubformControlName.txtID ...
```

Or to check the query:

```
If DCount("*","qryPendingCriteriaCIP")=0 Then
    MsgBox "No results"
Else
    Me.SearchResults.Form.RecordSource = "qryPendingCriteriaCIP"
End If
```

Comment: I tried your first way, and `If Forms!frm_SearchMulti!SearchResults.Form.RecordCount > 0 Then` and got runtime error 2465 both times.

Comment: I updated my question with some of the code which may or may not help.